# https RewriteBase Subdirectory .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have a number of stores and to save money i am now using a shared ssl certificate, shared between all my stores.

The problem i am having is that i use SEO Friendly urls, and when i use the shared ssl i causes errors, i have figured the problem out

because my shared ssl is http://my-shared-ssl.com/my_store the RewriteBase needs to be changed to  /my_store

My question is how do i change 
RewriteBase from **RewriteBase /** to **RewriteBase /my_store** only when using the shared ssl or when using port 80?

I am not very good with .htaccess and i am not sure where to start.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteBase /my_store
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule api/(.*)$ api.php?_d=$1&ajax_custom=1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css|ttf|svg|eot|woff)$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} store_closed.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/(.*)$ $2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: SSL cert is for particular domain(s) not for a particular URL in that domain.

Comment: the the destination of the shared ssl domain is the root then i just point it to a sub directory eg /my_store

Comment: ok post your existing .htaccess code in that case.

Comment: Can you please tell me what this `RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/(.*)$ $2 [L]` rule is actually trying to do?